# My navigation disappearing in 1038px width window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello guys my navigation is going under the navigation bar after a certain width how can I make it stay there at all times? code on fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedkna/0cm7zquh/

just decrease the width of the right-bottom corner of js fiddle and you will c that the `<ul>` goes under the main navigation bar disappears (It goes under the nav)

My solution with this was the float right but I can't drop the float right so any alternatives

HTML :

```
  <html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Turbo</title>`

  </head>
  <body class="body">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="includes/img/main_logo.png"></a>

                <a href="#" class="sign-in" id="color">Sign In</a>

                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href="">Get Started</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Products & Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tools & Tips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">After You File</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: left; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #0082c3; }

a:hover, a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #004f76; }

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0082C3;
  height: 75px; }

.nav-container {
  width: 84.7%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both; }

.nav img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.navigation {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px; }

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  float: left; }

.navigation li a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 15px 0 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 118%; }

.sign-in {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 26px 14px;
  width: 75px;
  font-size: 110%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #FF8000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; }

#color {
  color: #fff; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .nav-container {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

this works and we can change the max-width with the width in relative to our needs

Answer (score 0):

Your link bar is not disappearing, it is being pushed down below your other images.

If you set your .nav height to 160px, you will see the menu.

This won't help resolve your problem, but you can at least see where it is going.

Comment: I know and thats what I said at the first line of my topic :P

Comment: have you tried setting the min-width of your nav-container? min-width: 775px, will keep it there for you.

Comment: didn't change a thing all the same I mean the problem is the `float:right;` it makes the nav slip but as I said I can't change that any alternatives to float:right???

Comment: .nav-container {
  width: 84.7%;
  min-width: 775px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both; }